Data extract from Youtube Channel
I got the code to extract the list of the videos with titles and their links from YouTube. It works with videos only but not for the shorts. The codes are as:
Code 1:
var scroll = setInterval(function(){ window.scrollBy(0, 1000)}, 1000);

Code 2:
window.clearlnterval(scroll);
console.clear();
urls = $$ ('a');
urls.forEach(
    function(v,i,a) {
        if (v.id=="video-title-link") {
            console.log('\t'+v.title+'\t'+v.href+'\t')
        }
    }
);

I want the code to extract the list of shorts with titles and links and date of uploading from YouTube.
I want to extract the list of my YouTube shorts with titles, upload dates and links from my YouTube channel. The code above works for YouTube videos but not for YouTube shorts.

YouTube shorts have different classes or attributes compared to regular videos. Here’s a modified version of your script that should work for YouTube shorts:
// Function to extract YouTube shorts information using async/await
const extractYouTubeShorts = async () => {
    try {
        // Scroll down to load all shorts (adjust the scrolling interval as needed)
        const scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
            window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
        }, 1000);

        // Wait for enough time for the shorts to load
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));

        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        console.clear();

        // Select all anchor elements on the page
        const urls = document.querySelectorAll('a');

        // Iterate through each anchor element to find shorts
        urls.forEach(link => {
            // Check if it's a link to a short
            if (link.href.includes('/shorts/') && link.querySelector('#video-title')) {
                // Extract title and link
                const title = link.querySelector('#video-title').textContent.trim();
                const href = link.href;

                // Extract upload date if available (assuming it's nearby in DOM)
                const parentElement = link.closest('ytd-rich-grid-media');
                const dateString = parentElement.querySelector('#metadata-line span').textContent.trim(); // Adjust this selector based on your HTML structure

                // Log title, upload date, and link using template literals
                console.log(`${title}\t${dateString}\t${href}`);
            }
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error extracting YouTube shorts:', error);
    }
};

// Call the function to extract YouTube shorts information
extractYouTubeShorts();

